# Passing language characters between JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to pass special language characters like `ąėšų` from a JavaScript string into a URL and I would like to retrieve the string using the PHP GET method.

However I end up having different special language characters, somehow `ė` ends up being `Ä—`.

I have tried using `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the string in javascript and then using PHP's  `rawurldecode()` function to decode it, but nothing changes.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: You were right to encode the component you enter into the URL, you do not need to specially decode it. What you _do_ have to take care about is that either both sides, client and server, use the same character encoding or you have to convert, the first being the much more common and sense making option. Make sure you use UTF-8 encoding on the server and that this is also announced in the pages http headers and meta tags. Oh, and in php you need multi byte support, since otherwise only 8 bit encoding can be handled. Read about the multi byte extension and make sure it is loaded and used.

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP docs page for `rawurldecode()`, check the [note left by Javier](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php#80209). He mentions that some characters he encountered were not decoded properly. Possibly, you are experiencing a similar issue.

Edit: here is the code from the link just in case:

```
<?php
function urlRawDecode($raw_url_encoded)
{
    # Hex conversion table
    $hex_table = array(
        0 => 0x00,
        1 => 0x01,
        2 => 0x02,
        3 => 0x03,
        4 => 0x04,
        5 => 0x05,
        6 => 0x06,
        7 => 0x07,
        8 => 0x08,
        9 => 0x09,
        "A"=> 0x0a,
        "B"=> 0x0b,
        "C"=> 0x0c,
        "D"=> 0x0d,
        "E"=> 0x0e,
        "F"=> 0x0f
    );

    # Fixin' latin character problem
        if(preg_match_all("/\%C3\%([A-Z0-9]{2})/i", $raw_url_encoded,$res))
        {
            $res = array_unique($res = $res[1]);
            $arr_unicoded = array();
            foreach($res as $key => $value){
                $arr_unicoded[] = chr(
                        (0xc0 | ($hex_table[substr($value,0,1)]<<4)) 
                       | (0x03 & $hex_table[substr($value,1,1)])
                );
                $res[$key] = "%C3%" . $value;
            }

            $raw_url_encoded = str_replace(
                                    $res,
                                    $arr_unicoded,
                                    $raw_url_encoded
                        );
        }

        # Return decoded  raw url encoded data 
        return rawurldecode($raw_url_encoded);
}

print urlRawDecode("%C3%A1%C3%B1");

// output:
// áñ

?>
```